# Android Studio, Delay button

Tags: android, time, delay, android-button

```
int xp = 0;

public void practice(View v){

    xp = (xp+50);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xp);
    tv.setText("XP: " + xp);
}
```

I'm am new at android and I want my `Button` to be enabled and when you click it disable it for amount of time  . How could I do this? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void practice(View v){

    xp = (xp+50);

    yourBtn.setEnabled(false);
    handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, YOUR_DELAY);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xp);
    tv.setText("XP: " + xp);
}
```

`Handler` code is :

```
Handler  handler=new Handler();

Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call you delay logic or method here
           yourBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im getting errors everywhere saying "Can not resolve symbol"

Comment: handler and myRunnable

Comment: you must declare that variable as simple it is

Comment: Declare it as what though? Sorry i'm really new to this.

Comment: Thanks But now postDelayed is getting an error "Can not resolve method"

Comment: You must import os. Handler check your import part

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread btnEnabledThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
yourBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException i) {

                } finally {

yourBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        };
```

if you want to disable for 1 sec then use this code

```
btnEnabledThread.start();
```